# EF Core self referential many to many both sides

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have an entity that has a many to many onto itself

```
public class Docket
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<DocketDocket> RelateDockets{ get; set; }
}


public class DocketDocket
{
    public int LeftDocketId { get; set; }
    public Docket.Docket LeftDocket { get; set; }

    public int RightDocketId { get; set; }
    public Docket.Docket RightDocket { get; set; }
}
```

With the following config

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Joins.DocketDocket>().HasKey(t => new { t.LeftDocketId, t.RightDocketId });            
 modelBuilder.Entity<Joins.DocketDocket>().HasOne(pt => pt.LeftDocket).WithMany(t => t.RelatedDockets).HasForeignKey(pt => pt.LeftDocketId);
 modelBuilder.Entity<Joins.DocketDocket>().HasOne(pt => pt.RightDocket).WithMany().HasForeignKey(pt => pt.RightDocketId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

I then manually create the link in my repo as such

```
await base.Insert(new Joins.DocketDocket() { LeftDocketId = item.Id, RightDocketId = i.RightDocketId });
```

This works fine but I need this relationship to be double sided so I add the record for the other side

```
await base.Insert(new Joins.DocketDocket() { LeftDocketId = i.RightDocketId, RightDocketId = item.Id });
```

and on this second insert I get

`Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_RelatedDockets'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.RelatedDockets'. The duplicate key value is (10791, 10790).`

Shouldn't EF have my key as (10790, 10791) for the first entry and then (10791,10790) for the second one and therefore NOT duplicate? If not how can I define a unique key for this type of arrengement?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your config and need to modify Docker entity.

Config:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<DocketDocket>().HasKey(t => new { t.LeftDocketId, t.RightDocketId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<DocketDocket>().HasOne(m => m.LeftDocket).WithMany(t => t.LeftDockets).HasForeignKey(m => m.LeftDocketId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        modelBuilder.Entity<DocketDocket>().HasOne(m => m.RightDocket).WithMany(t => t.RightDockets).HasForeignKey(m => m.RightDocketId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Entity:

```
public class Docket {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<DocketDocket> LeftDockets { get; set; } = new List<DocketDocket>();

    public virtual List<DocketDocket> RightDockets { get; set; } = new List<DocketDocket>();

    public virtual List<DocketDocket> AllDockets => LeftDockets.Union(RightDockets).ToList();
}
```

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/m6tgDk